# Date format with time range in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datetime, format

I have a javascript date variable as `04/05/2015, 01:30` (dd/mm/yyyy, HH:mm) format. Now how can I change that format to `04/05/2015, 01:00-01:30` format. Ie, I want to change the time with time range where the first time value is always 30 minutes less than second time value. So If the date is `04/05/2015, 13:00` then the formatted date would be `04/05/2015, 12:30-13:30`

**EDIT:** See the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/ub942s6y/13/) for the sample.

Comment: What do you mean by 'javascript date'? Is it a string or Date? What should output be? String?

Comment: did you try to programm something what we can review?

Comment: see the added sample fiddle @Axel

Comment: Have you had a look at this library: http://momentjs.com/ It comes with tons of formatting and conversion methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the below solutions:

http://jsfiddle.net/ub942s6y/14/

> You need to change `data.addColumn('datetime', 'Date');` to 'string' as we are changing time

It will work fine. :)

Answer (score 1):

Im affraid that there is no out-of-the-box functionality for what you are asking, and you will have to write your own function for that.

Here is a js Date object specification : [Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Your new function return type cannot be Date, as this kind of formatting can be only achieved with string type.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have `date` object in that format. You will have manually create the format. It will be string.

```
var dateObj = new Date('04/05/2015, 01:30'), // input date 
    interval = 30,                           // interval in minutes
    remainingInterval = 0;

var hours = dateObj.getHours(),
    minutes = dateObj.getMinutes();
if(minutes > interval) {
    minutes = minutes - interval;
} else {
    remainingInterval  = interval - minutes;
    minutes = 60;
    hours = hours - 1;
    minutes = minutes - remainingInterval;
}
```

resulting date can be

```
console.log(dateObj.getDate()+'/'+dateObj.getMonth()+'/'+dateObj.getFullYear()+', '+dateObj.getHours()+':'+dateObj.getMinutes()+' - '+hours+':'+minutes);
```